# Describing curves of complex valued functions

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, curves, mobius-transformation

I wish to describe the curves $|f|$=constant and arg$f$=constant for the following functions:

1.$f(z)=exp(z^2)$

2.$f(z)=exp\left(\cfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$

My thoughts: I can write down what the compositions do to a complex number $z=x-iy$. But then I'm not sure what to do with the conditions $|f|=$constant and arg$f$=constant. Does the former restrict me to a circle and the latter, to a ray from the origin? Also I'm not sure what 'describe the curve' means.

I also know some random facts that for holomorphic function $f$ defined on a connected domain, each of the conditions $|f|=$constant and arg$f$=constant imply that $f$ is constant. I also know that the exp map takes the rectangular co-ordinates to polar co-ordinates.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: if you consider the logarithm of either of f above, what are its real and imaginary parts?

Comment: I see. So the real part is $u=\text{ln}|f(z)|$ and imaginary part is $v=\text{Arg}f(z)$. I'm stuck again. Where do I go from here?

Comment: The logarithm in both cases is nice, e.g.$z^2$ in the first, so you should easily find level curves for the imaginary part (hyperbolas in general, lines in the degenerate case) and then for the real part. Same with the other case, though there you get a simple mobius transform, so look up those